# Is there a way to maintain the style of an input element on :disabled? without writing same css again?

Tags: html, css

When using "disabled" on the textarea it changes its text-color and other attributes, how can I maintain the style of the textarea without having to write the same css inside textarea:disabled ? I only want to avoid providing inputs

```css
input, textarea {
outline: none;
border: none;
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: $ptsans;
font-size: rem(16);
color: $text-color;
@include placeholder {
    color: $placeholder;
}
background-color: #fff !important;
}

p {
line-height: rem(21);
}


textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  background-color:transparent!important;
  &.editable {
     width:97%;
     padding:10px;
     background-color:#fff!important;
     height:80px;
     border-color:#ced2db ;
     border-radius: 3px;
     border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
  }
}
textarea:disabled {
//Should I write all same styles here again?
}
```

Comment: Seems like you know how to combine selectors... why wouldn't you just use `textarea, textarea:disabled {}` instead of `textarea {}` and group the styles you want to apply to both there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a preprocessor to make final CSS there is an option to use "mixin" / "extend" - proper use depends on case. Please check docs. Plain old CSS selectors grouping can be also in handy, like that:

```
textarea, textarea: disabled {
    width: 100%;
    resize: none;
    /* other properties here... */
}
```